# fpdf error: Character "'" is outside the range of characters supported by the font used: "helvetica"

Tags: python, pdf, unicode, fonts, fpdf

I'm trying to generate a pdf using text scraped from a website, but I'm getting this error:

```
fpdf.errors.FPDFUnicodeEncodingException: Character "’" at index 30 in text is outside the range of characters supported by the font used: "helvetica". Please consider using a Unicode font.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I don't know what character it's talking about, since the text is scraped I don't know what the contents may be. This is my first time using fpdf and there isn't good documentation or general usage and explanation on fpdf or frankly any pdf generation tool out there, so assume I have 0 expertise with it.

Here's the function I'm using:

```
async def generate_pdf(data, indices, name, cover, path, list_ch=True):
    file_name = [name + f"({indices[0] + 1}-{indices[1]})" + ".pdf" if list_ch is True else name + ".pdf"][0]
    output_path = os.path.join(path, file_name)
    doc_name = data.title
    titles = data.df["Title"].iloc[indices[0]:indices[1]]
    chapter_content = data.df["Content"].iloc[indices[0]:indices[1]]
    chapter_dot_part = [str(data.df.at[index, "Chapter"]) + "." + str(data.df.at[index, "Part"]) for index in range(indices[0], indices[1])]

    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page("P", "A3")
    pdf.image(cover, 0, 0, w=297, h=420)

    pdf.add_page("P", "A3")
    pdf.set_xy(143, 0)
    pdf.set_font("Arial", "U", 30)
    pdf.write(txt=doc_name + "\n\n")
    pdf.set_font("Arial", "B", 20)
    pdf.write(txt="Table of contents\n\n")
    for title_index in range(len(titles)):
        chapter_name = f"Chapter {chapter_dot_part}: {titles[title_index]}\n"
        pdf.write(txt=chapter_name)

    for chapter in range(len(chapter_content)):
        pdf.add_page("P", "A3")
        pdf.set_xy(0, 0)
        pdf.set_font("Arial", "U", 23)
        pdf.write(txt=titles[chapter] + "\n\n")
        pdf.set_font("Arial", size=16)
        for line in chapter_content[chapter].find_all("p"):
            pdf.write(txt=line.text + "\n")

    pdf.output(output_path)
```

data is a pandas dataframe, indices is a tuple with a start and end index, cover is the path to a .jpg or .png file, in this case a .jpg, path is the destination path

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work with add_font using an existing DejaVu-Serif and DejaVu-Serif-Bold font from my computer. Weird because when I originally tried using add_font it said permission denied.

```
base_dejavu_path = '/snap/spotify/60/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/'
pdf.add_font('DejaVu', '', os.path.join(base_dejavu_path, 'DejaVuSerif.ttf'))
pdf.add_font('DejaVu', 'B', os.path.join(base_dejavu_path, 'DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf'))
```